# API google calendar

Tags: api, calendar, gmail

I use a booking plugin on my site that works with Google Calendar API.
Everything was working fine until I change the password of my account. When I try to recreate the authorization of the application, the google account page loops and never answer (the ram of the server is used 100%)
I tried to recreate a new project with a new API calendar, but I have the same result.
I do not quite understand the operation of the API, and reservations on my site have been blocked for 3days, it's a disaster!

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Why does Google API does not work on my site ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 - kindly look at this page which explains number of access tokens are limited in number.

4. Refresh the access token, if necessary.

Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.

Note: Save refresh tokens in secure long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. Limits apply to the number of refresh tokens that are issued per client-user combination, and per user across all clients, and these limits are different. If your application requests enough refresh tokens to go over one of the limits, older refresh tokens stop working.